# Weird infinite loop after migrating ASP.NET application from VS 2010 to VS 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, migration

We have an old but reliable ASP.NET Forms web application created with Visual Studio 2010 SP1 using the .NET 4 framework. We are aiming to move our development environment to Visual Studio 2015 and my first step has been to test the ASP.NET application in a VM with VS 2015 installed. Unfortunately I have hit a really weird issue and just can't work out what is causing the problem.

After migrating the project to Visual Studio 2015 (with no issues), I re-built it in VS 2015. The website comes up fine but after clicking the login button, the website goes into an infinite loop jumping between the Page_Load() event of the Login aspx page and the Page_Load() event of the master page (which the login page inherits from).

If I insert a Breakpoint on the first line of the Page_Load() event of login.aspx I can step line by line through this event and when it reaches the last statement in Page_Load(), it immediately jumps to the first line of the Page_Load() event of masterpage.master and if I step through that, it then re-enters the 1st line of the Page_Load event of login.aspx. This repeats forever!! The only deviation to this is that the first time through, it also steps into two empty events in Global.asax (Application_BeginRequest and Application_AuthenticateRequest).

I initially thought something stupid was happening in either of the Page_Load() events but it is just boring code that does very little. If I comment out all the code in both Page_Load() events and replace in each with `int x = 1;` I still get exactly the same behaviour.

I have gone back to the VS 2010 built version of the application and compared all the source code, configuration files etc and nothing is different. Both versions are running against the same OS (Windows 8.1 x64), browser (IE 11) and .NET framework installed. I have even built the VS 2010 version and deployed it onto the VS 2015 VM and found it works perfectly. My only conclusion is that something has changed after building it in VS 2015.

Any help would be hugely appreciated as I cannot work out what is causing this and have no idea how to investigate this further.

Comment: Well, you are right!  This is weird. I honestly don't know what's causing this, but I would try this:  Inside the 2015 solution, try deleting the master page and the login page, and then re-adding them.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Unfortunately rebuilding the master and login pages did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the problem ended up being a server control used to detect whether Javascript was enabled on the browser. This server control was a pre-compiled .NET DLL added to the ASP.NET project as an external reference. This DLL was unchanged in both the VS 2010 and VS 2015 versions of the ASP.NET project. To be honest, I still don't really understand how rebuilding the ASP.NET project in VS 2015 caused this but it must be some sort of backward compatibility issue.

Comment: How did you figure it out?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I just started removing stuff out of the login page until it started working!

Comment: Cool.  That was kinda the approach I was thinking when I said to delete them and start over.  Start re-building both pages item by item, testing with each one, until you find what makes it break.  You did the same thing, just in reverse.